# How to dismantle my own city

Tags: freeciv

I found a friendly city in a hut, but it's so freakish close from my other cities that I do not want to manage them both so close from one another.

**Is there a way to dismantle a city you own?**

Building settlers won't make it shrink to oblivion (the game won't allow it)

I do not think/do not know how it is possible to attack our own city with troops.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Double click city to bring up the City menu.
This should start in the overview tab. Click the settings tab, select "Disband if build settler at size 1"  Wait however many turns (make sure it won't grow before it finishes)

[image: Setting tab]

Answer (score 3):

The [answer by Foon](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/174438/) is the proper way to dismantle your own city. Here, I will show a cheat for dismantling your cities.

1. Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>e</kbd> to bring up the edit menu (the edit mode).

   [image: Freeciv edit mode]
2. In the menu, click on the city icon (one of the icons I surrounded with a black box in the image above).
3. Then, click on the red "X" icon in the menu.
4. Click on the city itself to remove it from the map.
5. Exit edit mode by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>e</kbd>.